# Is this Class thread safe? if not can someone explain a scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, safe-publication

I am trying to understand safe publication in case of Effectively Immutable classes. For my class I cannot come up with a scenario in which it would be thread unsafe. Do I need to add some other safe gaurd?

CLARIFICATION: Container elements are thread safe

```
 public class Container<E> {
    private LinkedList<E> data;

     public Container() {
        this.data = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    public Container(final Container<E> other) {
        this.data = new LinkedList<E>(other.data);
    }

    public Container<E> add(E e) {
        Container<E> other_cont= new Container<E>(this);
        other_cont.data.add(e);
        return other_cont;
    }

    public Container<E> remove() {
        Container<E> other_cont= new Container<E>(this);
        other_cont.data.remove(0);
        return other_cont;
    }

     public E peek() {
        if(this.data.isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No element to peek at");
        return this.data.get(0);
    }

     public int size() {
        return this.data.size();
    }
 }
```

Comment: If the elements are themselves thread unsafe, there could be issues. Say, for example, you have a Container<LinkedList>. You could theoretically call peek() to retrieve the same LinkedList in two separate threads, and then you have a problem.

Comment: For the sake of argument, lets say that the elements are themselves thread safe.

Comment: If add or remove can be called then it is unsafe and concurrent calls could corrupt the doubly linked list.

Comment: @Ben But as add and remove are not modifying the list itself, how is it unsafe?

Comment: i'm sorry, you're correct. I misread that. If you use copy-on-write then its safe

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine, as long as a `Container` is not published unsafely (which we should never do anyway).

But, for the sake of discussion, let's say a Container object is passed through unsafe publication

```
 static Container shared; // not volatile

 // thread 1
 shared = containerX.add( e );

 // thread 2
 shared.peek();
```

this is not thread safe; thread 2 can observe corrupt state.

To fix that, we'll need `final` variable; and all writes should finish before the constructor exit. In your code, you modify `other_cont` after `new Container`, which is the problem.

Personally, I would do it this way

```
 public class Container<E> {
    final private LinkedList<E> data;

    public Container() {
        this.data = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    Container(LinkedList<E> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Container<E> add(E e) {

        LinkedList<E> copy = new LinkedList<>(data); 
        copy.add( e );
        return new Container<>(copy);
    }

    ... etc
```

Rule of thumb for designing an immutable class - all fields must be `final`, and all writes must be done before constructor exit.

Comment: I assume you mean "safely"; Can you elaborate on your answer, are you suggesting some changes in the add remove methods?

Comment: @Suryavanshi oops, I need double-negative on that sentence.

Comment: final in `final private LinkedList<E> data;` only ensures that the reference points to the same LinkedList. It won't forbid any further mutation of the list

Comment: only Container class can modify it; and Container class never modifies it.

Comment: how come modifying the `other_cont` is a problem?? because IMHO each thread will always have a separate copy of `other_cont`

Comment: "only Container class can modify it; and Container class never modifies it" then why use final at all??

Comment: that is the intricate part ... I can link to the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1) ... the gist of it is that all writes must be done before constructor exit.

Comment: "why use final at all" - good question. `final` has two separate, unrelated semantics; 1st, it means the field cannot be rewritten; 2nd, it has some semantics for memory model. we don't really need the 1st in this class, but we do need the 2nd.

Comment: Point conceded on use of final, still what I don't get is the problem with modifying `other_cont` as its not published until the modification has finished

Comment: It fails if JVM does instruction reordering; however, `final` restrict that reordering.